# Efficiently select the number of multiprocessing workers

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing

I am designing an analysis program that I would like to work seamlessly across three systems.

> My home computer: 8 CPU cores and 16 GB of memory
>
> A workstation: 80 CPU cores and 64 GB of memory
>
> A super computing node: 28 CPU cores with 128 GB of memory

My program uses multiprocessing pool workers to run the slower steps in the analysis in parallel in order to save time. However, I've run into the issue that when I test my code I have trouble automatically setting an efficient number of sub-processes for the current system in `Pool(processes=*<process number>*)`.

Initially I tried to fix this by checking the number of cores available (`multiprocessing.cpu_count()`) and dividing that by some fraction. So set to 1/2, an 8 core system would use 4, an 80 core system would use 40, etc.

However, because the extreme difference in core to memory ratio across systems this often leads to lockups, when too many workers are created for the amount of memory, or wasted time, when the number of workers isn't maximized.

**What I want to know: How can I dynamically adjust the number of workers I generate across any system so that it always creates the most efficient number of workers?**

Comment: What would the criteria be for that dynamic allocator ?

Comment: @ljmc I suppose I would mainly need to know the number of cores a system has and the amount of memory. That way I could just do some testing to find an optimal ratio of workers per amount of RAM. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` already can give me the core count, I just need to get the memory somehow.

Comment: you are likely looking for the [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) library to get info on available ram. `psutil.virtual_memory().total`